# Pass integer input argument for Popen.communicate()

Tags: python-2.7, shell, popen

I am pretty new to python and I am stuck with something now. I am using python 2.7.
I am trying to automate a command in shell for which I wrote a python script. I have to input an integer value to the shell for which I am using Popen.communicate(input='2'). Though input is passed, it is passed as a string and the subprocess needs it as a numeric value. When I try to pass it as a numberic value like Popen.communicate(input=2) it throws the following error :

> TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**__getitem__**'

So is there any way to send the input as a numeric value ??

Here is the code I use :

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

cmd = ["sudo", "./sbt", "project java-examples", "run"]
proc = Popen(cmd, bufsize=4096, shell=False, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

string = proc.communicate(input='2')
print string[0]
proc.stdin.close()
```

Edit :
Sorry that I didn't mentioned this at the first place. 
My java application has multiple main classes hence the compiler ask which class to be executed, and I need to enter the same number every time,which is why I am trying to automate it. When I am passing a string value it throws numberformatexception.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate - *"The optional input argument should be a string to be sent to the child process"*, therefore no it's not possible. Which is good because pipes are texty, not Python-objecty, so it doesn't make sense for it to need a "numeric" value of 2 instead of a string "2". What does that mean? What actually happens when you pass `input='2'` ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler The subprocess needs a numeric input, not a string input, so when I pass a string value it throws a "Invalid number: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""   ". And changing input type for the subprocess is not an option as it's something prompted by the shell itself rather than the subprocess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for this.
Well the solution to this was pretty simple

---

when I changed

> string = proc.communicate(input='2')

to

> string = proc.communicate(input='2\n')

it worked fine.

Comment: The code that doesn't accept EOF as the end of a line is broken i.e., if the child process accepts `'2\n'` as the whole input then it should accept `'2'` too.

Answer (score 0):

The `./sbt` process you are calling needs to be able to read a string and convert it into a integer. It is not possible to send native Python types to a child process with only `Popen`.

Another potential solution would be to serialize the data into JSON, YAML, XML, python pickle format, etc - choose your standard. However as you are passing a single integer this would seem very much overkill.

Comment: changing input type for the subprocess is not an option as it's something prompted by the shell itself rather than the subprocess.

Comment: I think you are still not understanding what we are saying. stdin/stdout/stderr are ``str`` (Python3: ``bytes``) only. This is how Unix works. The subprocess can read a number as a string and then turn it into an integer - this is most likely. If you quote the code for the spawned process we might be able to help you more.

Comment: I am trying to run a java application and it has multiple main classes. So it prompts "Multiple main classes detected, select one to run: 
[1] TestProducer
[2] kafka.examples.SimpleConsumerDemo
[3] kafka.examples.KafkaConsumerProducerDemo
 "

Comment: So it sounds like your java application is reading a string. It might validate the string to ensure it can only be a digit 0 to 9, however it is still a string. So the code you quoted above, ``proc.communicate(input='2')`` should be correct. I think it is safe to assume it does not work however. I would suggest you start a new question, give more details for the case for passing as a string, and then ask why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes are byte streams in Unix. There is no numeric input -- there is only "string" input (there are no numbers or anything else -- there are only bytes).

If your child java process expects a number as its ascii representation then `.communicate(input='2')` is correct already if the subprocess reads from stdin (`System.in`). If the java process reads from the console directly (`System.console().readLine()`) then `stdin=PIPE` won't work (you might need to provide a pty in this case e.g., using [`pexpect`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/overview.html)).

For example, to read an integer from stdin and print it back in Java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadInteger
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("got " + i);
  }
}
```

To pass an integer from Python process to the Java process via a pipe:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['java', '-ea', 'ReadInteger'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
output = p.communicate(input='2')[0]
print 'from java {' + output.strip() + '}'
```

*It works* (the output is `from java {got 2}`).

It stops working if the child process reads from the console instead:

```
public class ReadIntegerConsole
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
    System.out.println("got " + i);
  }
}
```

The same python script leads to `NullPointerException` (and the output is `from java {}`) because `System.console()` is null here (stdin is redirected). It works if we provide a pseudo-tty:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import pexpect # $ pip install pexpect

child = pexpect.spawn('java -ea ReadIntegerConsole')
child.setecho(False)
child.sendline('2')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
child.close()
print "from java {" + child.before.strip() + "}"
```

*It works* (the output is `from java {got 2}`).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, but I am afraid it doesn't solve my problem. My exact problem is that the Java compiler finds multiple main classes and ask which one to be executed and I have to enter the same option every time which is why I am trying to automate it. And when a string '2' is passed it throws a numberformatexception.

Comment: @aladeen: don't put an essential for your question information in comments, edit your question instead (include the full stack trace). `pexpect` should work even if the tool that you use to launch your java program works with the console directly. It is a complex solution; I would try to pass a specific Java class name instead e.g., `['java', '-ea', 'ReadInteger']`. You should understand two things from my answer: (1) *"there are no numbers or anything else -- there are only bytes"* (2) [A process may bypass stdin and read the input from the console directly](http://goo.gl/WsYtYk).